Apple Keyboard - remap currency keys
I got a wireless keyboard Apple keybord for my MacBook Pro which has the Swedish keyboard-layout where shift + 4 prints out the € and alt + E prints out the $. I was used to have the dollar on shift + 4 (using the key a lot while programming) and wonder if it is possible to change only this two key-combinations. So my goal is to get the $ when pressing shift + 4 and the € when pressing alt + E. I did quite a bit of research but did only find ways to change functional keys like cmd or alt but nothing exactly like I need.
Summary:
My keyboard is set up in the way that

shift + 4 returns €
shift + E returns $

I would like the keyboard to act this way:

shift + 4 returns $
shift + E returns €

Any ideas how to re-map the keys like that?

Regardless what the keyboard's key label layout is, can you change the keyboard's language/type in the system settings somewhere?

Yes I could change to english format but I need to use the swedish keys å, ö and ä. They wouldn't be available anymore then.

The answer to any remapping like this is always Ukelele. Freeware.
